# Convert datetime format within ListView

Tags: django

I attempt to change the displaying format of datetime in template,

Here is my Codes in `views.py`:

```
class RestaurantListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return  RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Codes in template:

```
<ul> {% for obj in object_list  %}
    <li>{{ obj.city }},{{ obj.location }} {{ obj.category }}</li>
    <li>FirstVisit: {{ obj.visited }}</li>
        <br>
</ul>
```

Browser displays the datetime:

> FirstVisit: Sept. 9, 2015, 3:08 p.m.

I intend to convert to:

> FirstVisit: 2015-09-09 3:08 p.m.

So I import datetime in  `views.py` and format datetime object in template,

```
<li>FirstVisit: {{ obj.visited.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p') }}</li>
```

It reports error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:
Could not parse the remainder: '('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')' 
from 'obj.visited.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')'
```

How to change the format of datetime in template?

Comment: As is well documented, Django templates do not allow you to call methods with arguments.

Comment: Calling such methods can be done in the `views` file, not in template files.\

Answer (score 4):

in your template just use this

```
<li>FirstVisit: {{ obj.visited|date:'Y-m-d H:i'  }}</li>
```

just give the format you need in the format section

Comment: Needs `a` at the end for the "p.m.".